# CSS: How to align text to the center of the image (left side)

Tags: css

```
<p style="text-align:center;display:inline-block">yes </p>
<img width="50px" height="50px" src="">
```

[image]

How can I make the "yes" upper a bit, which align to the center position that image block?
What is a good practise way?

```
    ------
    |    |
yes |    |
    |____|
```

Comment: `vertical-align: middle;` is all you need

Comment: [Agreed ;)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19630163/css-how-to-align-text-to-the-center-of-the-image-left-side/19630181#19630181) - @Mr.Alien

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `vertical-align:middle;`. This will align the text and image the way you want.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gEGDn/)**

**The Code**

```
<p style="text-align:center;display:inline-block;">yes </p>
<img width="50px" height="50px" src="" style=" vertical-align:middle;">
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: in which element? <p> or <img> or make a new wrapper <div>

Comment: in `<img>`. See the demo mentioned in my answer above - @KitHo